# Using Module and path

Tags: powershell, using

I am running into some issues with loading a PSM1 file. The PSM1 is always in the same folder as the PS1, but that folder can change. It works if I use a literal path like this...

```
Using module '\\Mac\iCloud Drive\Px Tools 4.#\Dev 4.0\#Spikes\Windows7\library.psm1'
```

But that's useless since the code could be installed anywhere. And the code is signed, so it can't change.

It also doesn't work to use the new (in PS3.0) `$PSScriptRoot` automatic variable...

```
Using module "$PSScriptRoot\library.psm1"
```

Nor does a relative path or simple file name, as in...

```
Using module ".\library.psm1"
```

or...

```
Using module "library.psm1"
```

What am I missing, other than perhaps it's time to call it a day?

Also, note that the library contains classes, so other module loading options like `Import-Module` don't work. This has me wondering if perhaps classes are better supported in a later version, and I should really be targeting PS 6.0, rather than 5.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for more info on your problem, I came around this [blog post](https://info.sapien.com/index.php/scripting/scripting-classes/import-powershell-classes-from-modules). It says relative paths work, so have you tried using relative path with single quotes or without quotes?

Since values inside double-quotes [get evaluated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7) before passing them to the cmdlet, using them might not work.

Comment: Interesting. The root issue was the variable. Single, double or no quotes all work with a relative path. But I tried `Using module ".\library.psm1"` and it didn't work. The only difference today is the VM has been rebooted since then. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

you should run import-module first.
in PS1, I have add code to call import-module
like this:

```
ForEach($_ in  Get-ChildItem "$env:TEMP\*.psm1") {
    $checkModuleName = $_.Name -replace ".psm1"
    $importModule = $_.Name

    if (Get-Module $checkModuleName) {
        Write-Host "Update Module $importModule" -ForegroundColor Green

        Remove-Module $checkModuleName
        Import-Module "$env:TEMP\$importModule"
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Import Module $importModule" -ForegroundColor Green

        Import-Module "$env:TEMP\$importModule"
    }
}
```

when import done, I can used all module.

Comment: Hmm, how can you run Import-Modulke first, when Using must be the first non commented part of the script? Am I missing something here?

Comment: To clarify..  Import-Module can be used anywhere in code, and use variables for paths.  Unfortunately, Import-Module will not import classes from psm1 files.  For that, you have to use 'using', which cannot take Powershell variables for the path and must be on the first line.